# how to use ' '.join in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started learning python and while trying some exercises on codewars it stumbled upon the following solution:

`pairs = {'A':'T','T':'A','C':'G','G':'C'}
def DNA_strand(dna):
    return ''.join([pairs[x] for x in dna])`

Now what exactly does `return ''.join` do?

Comment: `''.join([pairs[x] for x in dna])` is an expression.  It is evaluated, and the result is the return value from the function.  That's how a `return` statement works.  As for the string method `join`, it creates a string from the elements of its argument, which is an iterable, separating them with the given string (in this case, an empty string).

Comment: Sorry my quiestion is actually what the quotation marks do

Comment: `''` is an empty string constant.  Type it into your interpreter and see.  It's the same as `""`.  `'abc'` is a string constant with 3 characters, `'a'` is a string constant with 1 character, and `''` is a string constant with 0 characters.  This is called an empty string.

Comment: ooh, alright. Thanks!

Comment: The [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) are always a good place to start with this kind of doubts

Answer (score 1):

It makes a string out of the list. The empty string (`''`) says that the string between each list element is nothing.

For example:

If `dna = ['A', 'T']` (keys) it returns the corresponding values `T` and `A` as the string `"TA"`.

In this example: `':'.join(...)` would return the string `"T:A"`